# Gnome 3.4 doesn't accept my desktop file

Tags: debian, gnome

I created many personal desktop files in my system, on debian

When I moved an installed desktop files from  /usr/share/applications to other directory. The entry is gone from the menu application of the Gnome desktop and that's is normal.

When I restored the desktop file in the /usr/share/applications the entry appears automatically. That's great too.

Today I created a new desktop file that didn't show itself. 
So I copied a working desktop file with a new name with few modification inside and nothing coming out. 
I used these comand :

```
 killall gnome-panel
```

and

```
xdg-desktop-menu install  xterm_ampere.desktop 
xdg-desktop-menu: filename 'xterm_ampere.desktop' does not have a proper vendor prefix
A vendor prefix consists of alpha characters ([a-zA-Z]) and is terminated
with a dash ("-"). An example filename is 'example-xterm_ampere.desktop'
Use --novendor to override or 'xdg-desktop-menu --manual' for additional info.
```

did'nt have any effect.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a permission problem. I did a `sudo chmod 744` on the file and the link showing itself in the menu bar.

Thanks